# Phone doesn't vibrate when I request it with Pyjnius

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, pyjnius

I'm trying to make my phone vibrate when a button is pressed but I can't make it work.

When I do `vibrator.vibrate(1000)` an error comes up in my console:

```sh
04-29 15:11:45.103 27494 27585 I python  :  Exception in thread Thread-1:
04-29 15:11:45.103 27494 27585 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
04-29 15:11:45.104 27494 27585 I python  :    File "/home/alexandrumarcel/projects/kivy-apps/rextester/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/python3-libffi-openssl-sqlite3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
04-29 15:11:45.104 27494 27585 I python  :    File "/home/alexandrumarcel/projects/kivy-apps/rextester/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/rextesterdroid/jnius/__init__.py", line 54, in jnius_thread_hook
04-29 15:11:45.104 27494 27585 I python  :    File "/home/alexandrumarcel/projects/kivy-apps/rextester/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/python3-libffi-openssl-sqlite3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/threading.py", line 865, in run
04-29 15:11:45.105 27494 27585 I python  :    File "/home/alexandrumarcel/projects/kivy-apps/rextester/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 117, in execute
04-29 15:11:45.105 27494 27585 I python  :    File "jnius/jnius_export_class.pxi", line 742, in jnius.jnius.JavaMethod.__call__
04-29 15:11:45.105 27494 27585 I python  :  jnius.jnius.JavaException: Invalid call, number of argument mismatch, got 1 need 4
```

I've tried adding multiple values (`vibrator.vibrate(0, 400, 200, 300)` but it generated another error:

```sh
04-29 15:21:19.065 27996 28101 F .rextesterdroi: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #10 pc 00036b4f  /data/data/demo.org.rextesterdroid/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/jnius/jnius.so (???)
04-29 15:21:19.308 27996 28101 F .rextesterdroi: runtime.cc:558]   native: #15 pc 00036b4f  /data/data/demo.org.rextesterdroid/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/jnius/jnius.so (???)
04-29 15:21:19.311 27996 28101 F .rextesterdroi: runtime.cc:558]   native: #04 pc 0000eb24  /data/data/demo.org.rextesterdroid/files/app/_python_bundle/modules/_ctypes.cpython-37m.so (_ctypes_callproc+728)
04-29 15:21:19.311 27996 28101 F .rextesterdroi: runtime.cc:558]   native: #13 pc 00036b4f  /data/data/demo.org.rextesterdroid/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/jnius/jnius.so (???)
04-29 15:21:19.311 27996 28101 F .rextesterdroi: runtime.cc:566]   native: #10 pc 00036b4f  /data/data/demo.org.rextesterdroid/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/jnius/jnius.so (???)
04-29 15:21:19.595 28105 28105 I crash_dump32: type=1400 audit(0.0:355029): avc: denied { open } for path="/data/data/demo.org.rextesterdroid/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/jnius/jnius.so" dev="mmcblk0p60" ino=2363865 scontext=u:r:crash_dump:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=file permissive=1
04-29 15:21:19.595 28105 28105 I crash_dump32: type=1400 audit(0.0:355030): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/data/data/demo.org.rextesterdroid/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/jnius/jnius.so" dev="mmcblk0p60" ino=2363865 scontext=u:r:crash_dump:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=file permissive=1
04-29 15:21:19.603 28105 28105 F DEBUG   :     #10 pc 00036b4f  /data/data/demo.org.rextesterdroid/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/jnius/jnius.so
```

```py
from jnius import autoclass

PythonActivity = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity')
Context = autoclass('android.content.Context')
activity = PythonActivity.mActivity

vibrator = activity.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from jnius import cast
from jnius import autoclass
PythonActivity = autoclass('org.renpy.android.PythonActivity')
activity = PythonActivity.mActivity

Context = autoclass('android.content.Context')
vibrator = activity.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE)

vibrator.vibrate(10000)
```

You missed the "vibrator.vibrate(10000)" line!

Answer (score 0):

There have been some changes from android api 25 to 26. I had the same problem and had to search the web for a solution. The difference to the old approach is, that you have to to get the system service and cast it along with the vibrator class to receive a valid vibrator object. The second change is the argument of the vibrate method. Now it takes a vibration effect object with one of its methods. CreateOneShot is only one methods you can use. You can also create wave forms or a composition (for more, see link below).

Vibration_Effect --> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/VibrationEffect

I hope, that I explained it understandable and that it works for you as well.

## Example

```
from jnius import autoclass, cast

PythonActivity = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity')
activity = PythonActivity.mActivity
Context = autoclass('android.content.Context')

vibrator_service = activity.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE)
vibrator = cast("android.os.Vibrator", vibrator_service)

vibration_effect = autoclass("android.os.VibrationEffect")       

# first argument of createOneShot is the time in ms
# second argument is the amplitude (range from 1 to 255), -1 is device standard amplitude
vibrator.vibrate(vibration_effect.createOneShot(2000, 150))
```

And don't forget to add the vibration permission in your spec file!

## buildozer.spec

```
# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = VIBRATE
```